# extract xml element in sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have the following xml stored in my database table.

I am trying to extract the Productid from the xml , I have been unsuccessful.
Could you tell me what changes I need to make to make the query work ?

**XML :**

```
DECLARE @Response VARCHAR(MAX) = '<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ProductId xsi:type="xsd:long" xmlns="http://nn.service.eservice_v1">30061</ProductId>
</Response>'
```

**Sql Query :**

```
select 
CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),@Response)).value('(/Response/ProductId)[1]','nvarchar(500)') as ProviderId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to store the XML in an XML type instead of converting from varchar.  If you are able to strip out all the namespace stuff, the following will work.

```
DECLARE @Response XML = '<Response><ProductId>30061</ProductId></Response>'

SELECT @Response.value('(//ProductId)[1]','nvarchar(500)') as ProviderId
```

If you are not able to strip out all the namespace stuff, then you will need to include the WITH XMLNAMESPACES clause

```
DECLARE @Response XML = '<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ProductId xsi:type="xsd:long" xmlns="http://nn.service.eservice_v1">30061</ProductId>
</Response>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://nn.service.eservice_v1' as e,
            'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi)
SELECT @Response.value('(/Response/e:ProductId)[1]','nvarchar(500)') as ProviderId
```